# C# Minimax process terminated due to stackoverflowexception

Tags: c#, minimax

I have been trying to create a tic tac toe game in C# with minimax functionality. Unfortunately I'm running into problems with getting the minimax function to correctly work.

```
    static double MiniMax(char[] gameState, int depth)
    {
        int bestMove = 0;
        double bestScore = -double.PositiveInfinity;
        if (maxDepth > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                if (ValidMove(i, gameState))
                {
                    char[] clone = new char[board.Length];
                    board.CopyTo(clone, 0);
                    clone[i] = 'X';
                    double score = 0;
                    score += MinPlay(clone, maxDepth--);
                    if (score > bestScore)
                    {
                        bestMove = i;
                        bestScore = score;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return bestMove;
    }

    static double MinPlay(char[] gameState, int depth)
    {
        if (Win(gameState)) return -1;
        if (Draw(gameState)) return 0;
        double bestScore = double.PositiveInfinity;
        if (maxDepth > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                if (ValidMove(i, gameState))
                {
                    char[] clone = new char[board.Length];
                    board.CopyTo(clone, 0);
                    clone[i] = 'O';
                    double score = 0;
                    score += MaxPlay(clone, maxDepth--);
                    if (score > bestScore)
                    {
                        bestScore = score;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
    }

    static double MaxPlay(char[] gameState, int depth)
    {
        if (Win(gameState)) return 1;
        if (Draw(gameState)) return 0;
        double bestScore = -double.PositiveInfinity;
        if (maxDepth > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                if (ValidMove(i, gameState))
                {
                    char[] clone = new char[board.Length];
                    board.CopyTo(clone, 0);
                    clone[i] = 'X';
                    double score = 0;
                    score += MinPlay(clone, maxDepth--);
                    if (score > bestScore)
                    {
                        bestScore = score;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
    }
```

I made these functions by using the guide here: http://giocc.com/concise-implementation-of-minimax-through-higher-order-functions.html

When running the program everything works fine until the computer has to take its turn. I get the error "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException".
I think this is caused by infinite recursion but after looking through the program for a while I can't tell what is causing it.

I have edited the code so that there is now a depth and the minplay and maxplay loops have a validmove check in them. The the computer now makes a move but for some reason it only ever chooses the first position. If the player chooses the first position as their first move the computer then chooses the position next to it and on the next turn it will over write the player on the first position. Then the computer stops making moves. I have no clue as to why this is happening.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I see MinPlay calls MaxPlay and MaxPlay calls MinPlay.

Comment: You have to have a depth value, or else it will run to long.

Comment: MaxPlay and MinPlay calling eachother is not the problem as there are base cases for when the game board evaluates to a win/loss.  The problem is you are not changing the game board by making 'valid' moves. You need to only apply an 'x' or 'o' to open squares.

Comment: Copy the code, don't type it.  depth is not the same as maxDepth.

Comment: You don't need a depth limiter in tic tac toe. A win/loss base case is all you need.

Comment: You should be modifying a copy of 'gameState' and not 'board'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your for loops in MinPlay and MaxPlay to only consider empty squares. It also looks like your not using the gameState that is being passed in. I don't know where board is defined.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{ 
    if (ValidMove(i, gameState) {
        char[] clone = new char[gameState.Length];
        gameState.CopyTo(clone, 0);
        clone[i] = 'X';
        double score = MinPlay(clone);
        if (score > bestScore)
        {
            bestScore = score;
        }
    }
}
return bestScore;
```

EDIT:

You changed it to score += which is incorrect.
Also, You have the incorrect score comparison in MinPlay.

```
    if (score < bestScore)
    {
        bestScore = score;
    }
```

Comment: I have added these changes to my code but the computer always chooses the 2nd position then it chooses the 1st and then it stops making moves. I'm starting to think there is a more fundamental issue with my approach to this problem. Thanks for all the help though.

Comment: Just got it working. Turned out that I forgot to reset the max depth. After running it again I realize that I don't need a max depth.

Comment: @jameshc Great job! Yeah the game tree of tic tac toe is so tiny you don't have to worry about depth.

Answer (score 0):

It is being caused because `MaxPlay` calls the function `MinPlay` which in turn calls the function `MaxPlay` again, and you aren't doing anything to change the gamestate after each successive call to cause the recursion to end. You just toggling clone[0] between 'o' and 'x', your functions never complete an iteration of the for loop.